Get the Message from the MQ Queue on the basis of Put Time?
How can I filter the messages from IBM MQ queue in IIB ACE and pick only those messages which are there for more than 5 minutes filtering on the basis on put time?

JMS Messages have a JMSTimestamp field, which holds the time the message was sent.
You could create a selector based on
String messageSelector = "JMSTimestamp <= " + System.currentTimeMillis() - (1000 * 60 * 5);

...

receiver = (MessageConsumer) session.createConsumer(replyQueue, messageSelector);

